# What WebKit version is Qt 5.4.1 using on OSX?

Tags: qt, webkit, qtwebkit, capybara-webkit

How could I inspect this from the terminal?

I have already tried `qmake -v` but that only gives

```
› qmake -v
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.4.1 in /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.4.1/lib
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any qtwebkit, you can find webkit version at `Version.xcconfig` file in webkit folder. Sample link is https://github.com/qtproject/qtwebkit/blob/v5.4.1/Source/WebKit/mac/Configurations/Version.xcconfig. Reason for providing github link is that, tomorrow if you need to find webkit version corresponding any other qtwebkit version, simply change the tag.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is an even more awesome answer than the one before!

Answer (score 5):

Create a python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from PyQt5.QtWebKit import qWebKitVersion

print(qWebKitVersion())
```

Or compile a simple c++ snippet:

```
#include <qwebkitversion.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << qWebKitVersion().toLatin1().data() << std::endl;
}
```

and `webkitver.pro`

```
QT += webkit
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

Comment: I tried the python script, but I'm getting `› python QtWebKit-version.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "QtWebKit-version.py", line 3, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWebKit import qWebKitVersion
ImportError: No module named PyQt5.QtWebKit`

Comment: You need to install python3-qwebkit package.

Comment: ah, what's the brew package called?

Comment: Try `python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit`

Comment: `› brew install python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit
Error: No available formula for python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit`

Comment: I don't have brew around right now. Try `brew search`

Comment: Ok. Seems it's not so straightforward on my system: http://danmarner.com/2014/04/23/Installing-PyQt5-with-Python-3-On-OS-X.html

Comment: Got it working! `› python QtWebKit-version.py` outputs `538.1` so that seems to be the WebKit version Qt 5.4.1 is using. Atleast on my system (OSX 10.9.5 Mavericks).

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20150415130105/http://danmarner.com/2014/04/23/Installing-PyQt5-with-Python-3-On-OS-X.html since that site seems to have gone down sometime in early 2016.